# Change how JSX curly braces evaluates an Object/Class Instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following snippet of code:

```
import React from 'https://esm.sh/react@18.2.0'
import jsxToString from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/jsx-to-string@1.4.0";

class T extends Function {
  foo;
  constructor(foo) {
    super();
    this.foo = foo;
    
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply: (target) => target._call()
    });
  }
  bar() {
    return this.foo + 'bar';
  }
  toString() {
    return this.bar();
  }
  _call() {
    return this.bar();
  }
}

const a = new T('foo');

const el1 = (<div>{`${a}`}</div>);
const el2 = (<div>{a()}</div>);
const el3 = (<div>{a}</div>);

console.log(jsxToString(el1))
console.log(jsxToString(el2))
console.log(jsxToString(el3))
```

The output is the following:

```
"<div>foobar</div>"
"<div>foobar</div>"
"<div>...</div>"
```

I know this is weird but long story short, I ***need*** to be able to represent my `a` object the same way however I pass it through JSX curly braces.

`` {`${a}`} `` => calls toString **OK**
`{a()}` => calls _call **OK**
`{a}` => **KO**, I suspect that this syntax does something like `eval(a)` so it end up failing.

Is there a way to force how an object is evaluated when passed through JSX curly braces?
I am open to any suggestion, I don't care about performance or anything, think of it as a proof of concept.

The only requirement is that I can't change the JSX syntax.

Comment: Go to https://babeljs.io/repl and see what happens to JSX when converted to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible.

There are no "instance getters" in javascript. I.e. you can write getters for properties,
but not for the object itself.

#### JSX evaluation

The code between the curly braces in JSX is just normal javascript code
(i.e. no `eval()` is happening or something).
Your JSX code will be converted to plain javascript:

```
const el1 = React.createElement( "div", null, `${a}` );
const el2 = React.createElement( "div", null, a() );
const el3 = React.createElement( "div", null, a );
```

#### React elements

The [3rd parameter of createElement](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createElement#parameters) is
expected to be a React node, i.e. a React element, string, number and some others.

So you would need to e.g. make `a` be a React element,
which can also be called as a function, and you'd need to overwrite it's
`toString` method, but React elements are not extensible, so that is no option.

In fact, [React states this explicitly](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement#caveats):

> You must treat React elements and their props as immutable and never
> change their contents after creation

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, I tried to extends native types (String mostly) or React Component and event crreating customElements, to no avail. I tried though :D